# Как пользоваться документацией Java?

Tags: java

Два идентичных примера, но способ работы разный. Как понять какой?

**Сортировка**

1 - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html метод sort
Чтобы его вызвать я должен у класса вызвать Arrays.sort(array);

2- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator- тоже метод sort
Но, я в классе его вызвать уже не могу. `ArrayList.sort` уже работать не будет

И как понять где мне вызывать метод у класса или у объекта? Наугад?

Сначала попробовать у класса, и потом у объекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метку [oracle] следует использовать **только** для вопросов, связанных с сервером баз данных Oracle. См. описание метки. Удалено.

Comment: Правило простое, static метод вызывайте у класса, нестатический - у объекта.

Comment: Спасибо. Точно! Я забыл про static. Это же очевидно. Здоровья вам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наугад ничего "тыкать" не нужно, советую начать с изучения Java Core, коллекций и встроенных в джаву классов для работы с ними.

Метод `sort` интерфейса `List` требует указания компаратора (см. интерфейс `Comparator`). Компаратор нужен, если вы хотите сортировать объекты, а не просто `Integer`.

Но в вашем простом случае есть решение использовать `Collections.sort(...)`:

```
Collections.sort(integerArrayList);
```

Метод берет вашу коллекцию и сортирует объекты внутри нее. После сортировки обратитесь к коллекции и увидите, что объекты в ней отсортированы.

Comment: Да, в том-то и дело, что core я уже все тесты сдал и прошёл. Вот как вы поняли, что перед использованием метода sort нужно добавить Collections. Ведь про это ни слова. Почему в разделе Arrays я могу использовать Arrays.sort В разделе ArrayList тоже есть метод sort, но я уже не могу использовать ArrayList.sort? А в текущем примере я вообще должен использовать Collections

Comment: @ДядяФёдор тут на самом деле логически все просто. Смотрите, если вы хотите использовать утилитный класс для массивов, то смотрите на возможности `Arrays`, если коллекция, то `Collections`. Иногда методов, реализованных в этих интерфейсах достаточно. Но когда вы окажетесь в ситуации, что нужного функционала в них недостаточно, тогда уже вам нужно самостоятельно реализовывать сортировки и т.д.

Comment: Такова реализация спецификации Java, что в интерфейсе `List` метод `sort` должен принимать компаратор, в котором вы опишите самостоятельно порядок сортировки.

Comment: @ДядяФёдор если ответил на ваш вопрос, тогда примите, пожалуйста, ответ